# ZF2- Can't access a controller action using jQuery.ajax on zend framework 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery, zend-framework2

in order to set two dependent drop downs i'm using jQuery.ajax, but i have some troubles and i think the url of the controller action i set on my $.ajax is not accessible.

this is my controller action code :

```
 public function fillIncidentsAction()
      {
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->isPost())
            {
                $code_categ = (int) $request->getPost('code_categ',0);           
                $data = new JsonModel(array(
                    'success' => true,
                    'results' => $this->getTableInstance('TypeIncidentTable')
                                        ->getListTypeIncident($code_categ),
                ));
                return $data;

            }
        }
```

and this is the main part of my js function

```
$('#'+source).change(function() {

    if($('#'+source).val() != '')
     {

        $.ajax({
            type:  'POST',
            async: false,
            url:   url,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  { code_categ: $('#'+source).val() },
            success: function(data){
            alert(data.success);//<------ i added this to test if this function is executed or not

                if(data.success)
                {
                    $('#'+target).prop('disabled', true);
                    if(data.results != ""){
                        var options = new Array();
                        $.each(data.results, function(key, value){
                           options[((key) ? key : 0)] = '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
                        });
                        $("#"+target).html(options.join(''));

                        $('#'+target).prop('disabled', false);;
                    }
                }
            },


        });
```

I don't know where i'm wrong. Any suggestions? 
Thanks for help !

Sorry, this is how i set my url :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "<?php echo $var =$this->url('gims/default', array('controller' =>       'evenement', 'action' => 'fill_incidents')); ?>";

// initialize the js function
dependentDropDown('firstList','secondList',url);
});
</script>
```

Hope this will give you more details.

Comment: `url:   url,` and where exactly is url defined?

Comment: Needs more information. The code of how you set up your route, the controller name, and the value of url JavaScript variable.

Comment: the url is defined on the view.

Comment: @Adrian, i've just added the missing code !

Comment: What's the result you get from the request? Check the "Network" tab in your web inspector (Firefox or Chrome) as it tells you what the response is. Is the status code 200? If so, what is the response body? If the status code is 404 or 500, what's the error message you got?

Comment: @JurianSluiman : The response is `200 OK`, `type =text/html`, the `size = 318 B` and `content =0 B`. What can we deduce from this ?

Comment: @MounirHamoudi if you would get a 404, it means the route didn't match. A 500 would mean you've got a configuration/runtime error somewhere in your code. 200 means that the response did succeed, only it didn't return a thing. Have you enabled the Json rendering strategy?

Comment: effectively, in my module.config.php i enabled the Json stategy and now it works as expected. Thanks @JurianSluiman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my moodule.config.php, i haven't enabled the Json strategy.

```
'view_manager' => array(
          //...
'strategies' => array(
                'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),

        ),
```